# How to assign the option values for <form:select> from controller using properties file?

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I am a beginner to Spring MVC. And I want to know how to assign the option values from my controller. And how to pass the values to select values?

**msg.properties**

```
 num=1,2,3
```

**test.java**

```
 import java.util.List;
 import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
 import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
 import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

 @Controller
 public class test {

   @Value("#{'${num}'.split(',')}")
   private List<String> num;

   @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String getproperties(ModelMap model) {
    model.addAttribute("num", this.num);
    return "zzz"
  }
```

**zzz.jsp**

```
 <body>
 <form>
    <select>
       <option value="NONE"> --SELECT--</option>
       <option items="${num}"></option>
    </select>
 </form>
 </body>
```

Comment: For God shake please follow some  coding standards.

Comment: @ComponentScan(basePackages = "yourpackage path")
@PropertySource("classpath:values.properties"), Provide these annotation on class and then use your @Value annotation.

Comment: do you have servlet-context.xml? and do you use maven for dependencies?

Comment: Yeah,I have used both(servlet-context.xml,maven dependencies) @ken Bekov

Answer (score 1):

First of all be sure that `msg.properties` is in resource directory and included into your application. For example you can put this file in `resources` directory in root of you project, then add to `build` section of *pom.xml*:

```
<build>
...
  <resources>
     <resource>
        <directory>resources</directory>
     </resource>
  <resources>
</build>
```

At the next step you need to add property placeholder to `servlet-context.xml`:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
   <property name="locations">
      <list>
         <value>classpath:msg.properties</value>
      </list>
   </property>
</bean>
```

After that you can inject property to controller:

```
     @Controller
     public class test {

           @Value("${num}")
           private String numString;

           @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
           public String getproperties(ModelMap model) {
              String [] numArray = numString.split(",")
              model.addAttribute("numArray", numArray);
              return "zzz"
           }
     }
```

You didn't specify, do you use template engine, or not. But if you are using JSTL:

```
 <%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
 <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
 <html>
 <head>
    <title></title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <form>
    <select>
       <option value="NONE"> --SELECT--</option>
       <c:forEach items="${numArray}" var="item">
          <option value="${item}"/>${item}</option>
       </c:forEach>
    </select>
 </form>
 </body>
```

Comment: thank you very much.. please tell me,shall i add anything in my web.xml?

Comment: @user5497465 you are welcome. there is nothing needs to be changed in web.xml. if my answer was really helpful, don't forget mark it.